# ¿Como puedo bloquear cualquier conexión remota mediante ssh?

Tags: ubuntu, seguridad, ssh

Estoy intentado bloquear cualquier conexión remota por ssh. Se que para eso debo modificar mi fichero /etc/ssh/ssh_config, pero no se que poner. Solo he leído como bloquear el acceso root, pero no se si eso me bloquearía cualquier acceso.

¿Alguien sabe como bloquear completamente el acceso remoto?

Este es el código que hay dentro:

```
Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
#   RhostsRSAAuthentication no
#   RSAAuthentication yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   Port 22
#   Protocol 2,1
#   Cipher 3des
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: MIrando el `manual de sshd_config` parece que `DenyGroups *` los bloquearía a todos. Por otra parte, si lo que quieres es que nadie use el acceso vía SSH, ¿y si simplemente cierras al servicio?

Comment: Es una práctica en la que debo simplemente no permitir que nadie se conecte. No he abierto el servicio en ningún momento. Nos dan todo implementado en una maquina virtual. No me han dicho como, ni hay información. Nos las tenemos que apañar y nunca he hecho nada de eso. No se cerrar el servicio jajaja. Voy a probar tu opción. Muchísimas gracias por tu tiempo.

PD: añade esto como respuesta, no como comentario. ¡Si funciona no puedo ponerlo como respuesta correcta y que te lleves esos puntillos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple vista, y mirando el [manual de sshd_config](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config), se me ocurre que podrías jugar con las opciones `DenyUsers` o `DenyGroups` y definirlas de manera que apliquen a todos los usuarios o grupos, respectivamente.

En particular, yo lo intentaría indicando:

```
DenyUsers *
```

Pue `*` es un patrón definido en la sección de [PATTERNS](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) y que coincide con cualquier valor que consista en cero o más caracteres. Por tanto, todo nombre de usuario coincidirá y `sshd_config` los bloqueará.

---

Alternativamente, lo que estás intentando es bloquear una conexión remota vía SSH. Y si lo que no quieres es que entren por la puerta, probablemente lo más fácil es... que no haya puerta. Por tanto, siempre puedes considerar desactivar el servicio:

```
sudo service sshd stop
```

Nótese que esto lo parará, pero se reiniciará cuando la máquina se levante otra vez. Si quieres que este cambio sea permanente, en Ubuntu deberás ejecutar el comando:

```
update-rc.d -f sshd remove
```

Si quieres recuperar el servicio tal y como estaba antes, deberás decir:

```
update-rc.d -f sshd defaults
```

Comment: ¿Pero la desactivación de ese servicio se mantiene aunque apague la maquina, o cuando se reinicia el ordenador se vuelve a conectar y tengo que hacer algún script para que se ejecute en el arranque del SO?

Comment: @AlfonsoRodríguez buena pregunta. Añadí detalle de cómo pararlo permanentemente y que no se active al arrancar el SO

Comment: Perfecto! Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: @AlfonsoRodríguez ¿probaste si funciona?

Comment: Si! He hecho un par de pruebas y me ha funcionado. Aun me quedan una batería de pruebas, pero por ahora pinta bien. Gracias!